# How can we define the new Music/Video iOS apps?

Tags: discussion

iOS 5 brought us Music and Video as two seperate apps, these cannot be tagged correctly as the description for Music relates to songs and sond that is playing not the app, and the same applies to video.

Does anyone have any suggestions for creating tags specfically for these apps?

Answer (score 2):

While not ultra-elegant, I've found myself referring to these programs as Music.app, Video.app and, to extend the system, Mail.app to distinguish the application from the overall concept.

I am suggesting this "without ego" because I agree (in advance) with those who find the solution ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: `Music.app` and `Videos.app` are certainly the most common names given when not just generally calling them "the Music app" or "the Music player". Akin to, as you said, `Mail.app`, `Settings.app`, etc.

Comment: We already have a `mail.app` tag, so I think this is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to leverage the existing hyphen methodology:

music-app

video-app

mail-app

The last would presumably be further refined through the use of additional operating system tags.

This approach is somehow less "ugly" to my eye.  It doesn't modify the names of the applications as we normally see them.

Comment: You actually answered the question about tagging itself! Well said. I agree that I think that style makes sense for a few different reasons.

Comment: I foresee a little confusion with mail.app, unless the correct 10.7 or iOS-5 etc tag is used in conjunction, it may not be totally clear.

Comment: Hence my comment about using a second tag to clarify. This would be a problem for either of these tag styles. The bigger issue that I see is that  multiple OS tags and a "specific search" may cause answers to general questions about mail.app (for either device family) to be missed. It's an imperfect world.